# How does an OWIN authentication cookie actually authenticate

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, cookies, owin

To authenticate a user, what information is stored in the cookie generated by the default implementation of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager.SignIn(claimsIdentity)`?

Chrome / FF do not clear cookies that don't have an expiration date (depending on the users browser settings). So even non-persistent, cookie-authenticated users stay logged in over browser restarts.

The users even stay signed in after the app-pool recycles, which is what prompts me to ask this question.

Does the cookie contain session specific information, or is it the same as a persistent cookie, but without an expiration date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, the cookie generated contains multiple field among them are the user-id and an expiration datetime for the cookie. The data is encrypted with the machine key of the web server which makes the cookie that sent to the browser.

So after a web app is restarted the machine key remains the same and the cookie is still usable as long as the expiration has not past.

Comment: Thanks David. I haven't defined a machine key in my web.config. Is this generated automatically? If so, presumably it stays the same over app-pool recycles?

Comment: Yes it is by default auto generated for each app pool (or web identity) within IIS and remains the same until you define it in the web config. so it will remain the same over recycles.